# Does Facebook API allow for 3rd party wall posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does Facebook API allow for a 3rd party app or service to make wall posts on behalf of a user?

For example, I have a gaming app that will require that a user write 10 wall posts in advance and then give the gaming app the 'rights' to post these messages on behalf of the user throughout the week.

If yes, can the same feature be extended to private messages?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook allows wall posts through an app on behalf of the user – but what the [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) **don’t** allow, actually **forbid**, is what you’re trying to do:

> You must not incentivize users to use [...] Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'm not incentivizing the users, it will be up to them to allow my gaming app to make wall posts on their behalf.

Comment: And what if the _don’t_ allow it …? If thereby they should have _any_ kind of disadvantage in your game or maybe wouldn’t even be allowed to enter something, that means you actually __are__ “incentivizeing” them … It’s up to you in the end, I’m just mentioning it because some people aren’t aware of these restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes almost anything is possible using the facebook API.  You are probably best to look at the API itself for more information, but it is very simple.  Using android you create a facebook object, this allows you to carry out the authentication, after that depending on which access you have asked for you can send POST requests to facebook from your app which creates a message/ wall post/ post on someone elses wall/ lists your friends amoungst many many other things.

Comment: Thank you.  Just to clarify, if my gaming app eventually has 50 users and with the right permission/auth structure; I can make a wall post on behalf of any of these users on their own respective facebook wall?

Comment: If the user is logged into your app then your app given the right permissions may make posts to their wall on their behalf.  The user must be logged in though, either via single sign on (using the official facebook app) or by using the standard oAuth authentication (which comes up as a facebook login page inside your app.